# Solve in $\mathbb{N}$ the equation $3x^2 + 2x = y^2$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, prime-numbers, diophantine-equations

> Solve in $\mathbb{N}$ the equation $3x^2 + 2x = y^2$.

After factoring, we get $x(3x+2)=y^2$. If LHS is a perfect square and we let $x = n^2z$, where $z$ is not divisible by the square of any prime number, and $3x+2 = zk^2$ and I got stuck here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is a Pell equation, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/616051/linear-recurrence-solution-to-diophantine-equation?noredirect=1), or others like [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3062058/solve-an2bnc-k2-over-the-integers?noredirect=1), completing the square.

Answer (score 2):

This can be reduced to a Pell's equation.

$$x(3x +2) = y^2$$

$$(x,3x+2) = (x,2)$$

Assume $x$ to be even. Then the equation is reduced to,

$$k(3k+1) = (\frac{y}{2})^2$$

Here as $(k,3k+1) = (k,1)$, $k = a^2$ and $3k+1 = b^2$

Pell's equation.
$$3a^2 + 1 = b^2$$

$x = 2a^2$ and $y = 2ab$

Edit:

Pell's equation has infinite solutions, this can be shown.

$a= 1$ and $b = 2$ is a pair solution.

Observe: $$(2+3^{\frac{1}{2}})(2-3^{\frac{1}{2}}) = 1$$

$${((2+3^{\frac{1}{2}})(2-3^{\frac{1}{2}})})^n = 1^n$$

By binomial expansion.

$$(2+3^{\frac{1}{2}})^n = x_n +y_n3^{\frac{1}{2}}$$
$$(2-3^{\frac{1}{2}})^n = x_n -y_n3^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

$${((2+3^{\frac{1}{2}})(2-3^{\frac{1}{2}})})^n = 1^n = x_n^2-3y_n^2$$

For every $n$ there is a solution,

$n=2$

$$(2+3^{\frac{1}{2}})^2 = 7+4.(3)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$
$$x_n = b = 7,y_n = a = 4$$

This works also.

If odd then, $(x,2)=1$

$x = z^2$

$3x +2 = f^2$

Which can not happen as we are getting $f^2 \equiv 2 \pmod{3}$

Comment: What does this mean $$(x,3x+2) = (x,2)$$

Comment: This means the gcd is same, 

(x,3x+2) = (x,3x+2 -3x) = (x,3x+2)

this comes from euclid's division lemma

a = bq+r
(a,b) = (b,r) = (b,a-bq)

Comment: How did you get $x = 2a^2$ and $y = 2ab$

Comment: as $x = 2k$ and k = $a^2$ and $3a^2+1 = b^2 = 3k+1$

$(3k+1)(k) = (y/2)^2$

Comment: Don’t we have to solve Pell’s equation to find a and b?

Comment: Yea, if you want me to add how to solve it i can,

$x^2 = 1+dy^2$ is a pells equation where $d$ is not a square.

Comment: Can you please add how you solved $$3a^2 + 1 = b^2$$

Comment: There, added it

Comment: @math.enthusiast9 I would recommented to look into other ways of solving pell's equation by searching also.

Comment: For continued fractions and pell's equation, see [this pdf by Olds](http://www.ms.uky.edu/~sohum/ma330/files/Continued%20Fractions.pdf) and chapter 1 (specifically) of [this pdf by khinchin](https://elasticbeanstalk-us-east-2-497500429547.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/a06_cont_frac_Khinchin.pdf).  See also [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2749487/algebra-direct-connect-pell-eqn-soln-p-nk-q-nk-with-p-n-q-n-sqrtd/2752161?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C23.4532#2752161).

Answer (score 1):

Multiply by $3$ and set $z:=3x$ to find that
$$3y^2=9x^2+6x=z^2+2z=(z+1)^2-1,$$
and hence for $X:=z+1$ and $Y:=y$ we get the Pell equation
$$X^2-3Y^2=1.\tag{1}$$
This equation is well studied, see [Wikipeda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation#List_of_fundamental_solutions_of_Pell%27s_equations) for example. Every solution $(X_n,Y_n)$  to $(1)$ is of the form
$$X_n+Y_n\sqrt{3}=(2+\sqrt{3})^n,$$
for some integer $n$. You get a solution to the original equation whenever $X\equiv1\pmod{3}$, which is whenever $n$ is even.