# About the diophantine $x^2 + t(n) \space y^2 = n $.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, supremum-and-infimum, pell-type-equations

Consider the diophantine

$$ x^2 + t(n) \space y^2 = n $$

Where $x,y> 0$, $ n>1$  and $t(n) > -1$.

For a given $n$ we want to find the smallest possible integer $t(n)$.

Clearly when $n$ is a square then $t(n) = 0 $.
When $ n = a^2 \space b $ then $ t(n)$ is at most $t(b)$.
If $ n $ is a prime 1 mod 4 then $t(n) = 1 $.
Also $ t(n) < n$ is trivial as $1^2+(n-1)1^2=n$

Clearly, primes of type $s \mod d$ with prime $d$ and $s > 0$ are related. 
And trivially Pell’s equation, and hence also continued fractions are related.

I have seen a lot of related things but I have not seen $t(n)$ discussed.

What is known about $t(n) $ ??

The sequence starts like

$$ t(2) = 1, t(3) = 2 , t(4) = 0 , t(5) = 1 , t(6) = 2 , t(7) = 3 , t(8) = 1 , t(9) = 0 , ... $$

I could not find it on the OEIS.

Comment: Related: I've written a little bit about the number of solutions to $x^2+ay^2=n$. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2834085/how-many-integer-pairs-satisfy-the-ellipse-x2ay2-r/2836230#2836230

Comment: Can you write out the first few $t(n)$s?

Comment: $ t(2) = 1, t(3) = 2 , t(4) = 0 , t(5) = 1 , t(6) = 2 , t(7) = 3 , t(8) = 1 , t(9) = 0 , ... $

Comment: I considered using theta functions but it did not work out.

Comment: We do not have a Pell-type equation here because such an equation must have the form $x^2-dy^2=n$ with a positive integer $d$

Comment: If $n$ is not a perfect square, than there is a unique positive integer $k$ with $k^2<n<(k+1)^2$ giving $0<n-k^2<2k+1$ , which gives the bound $t(n)<2k+1<2\sqrt{n}+1$